# Why list index out of range?

Tags: python-3.x

```py
count = [0]*1001
count[1000] = 0
```

Getting this issue on LeetCode, and ran into this.  I would expect the above to create 1001 elements, or 0 to 1000 valid positions.  But getting a list index error instead.

Comment: I just tested your code in the python repl and it works fine – no `IndexError` is raised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've ran your code in the command line with python 3.8.0 and no IndexError was flagged? Is this the exact code your getting the error from or is a similar example to the code you're using?